# Laravel 8 api with passport keeps getting Method not found on postman

Tags: php, laravel

am trying to get Passport to work on Laravel 8 but keep getting the "Method not allowed" error. Meanwhile it works fine with GET routes

```
Route::post('/token', 'AuthController@requestToken');
 Route::post('/login', 'UsersAuthController@login');
  
 Route::get('/logout', 'UsersAuthController@logout');
 
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: show us the error

Comment: have you use /api prefix? it is like https://example.com/api/login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I figured it out my mistake I was not adding the "https://" part of the url which I assume causes a redirect that makes the route treat the request as GET instead of post.